# Understanding addressing of strings in 2D arrays

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
 void main()
{
  char s[10][10];
 int i;

 for(i=0;i<4;i++)
      scanf("%s",s[i]);
 printf("%s",s);
 printf("%s",s+1);
 printf("%s",s[1]+1);
}
```

When I type the above line of code first `printf` statement will print the first string and second `printf` will print the second string since `s[1]` is equivalent to `s+1`. But the third `printf` will print the second string starting from the second character.

If `s[1]` is equivalent to `s+1` why `s[1]+1` does not give the result of `s+2`?

I do not get the idea of address calculation for 2D string array.

Answer (score 4):

The way pointer arithmetic works, `s[i]` is equal to `*(s + i)`.  So `s[1]+1` is actually `*(s + 1) + 1`, which is not the same as either `s + 2` or `*(s + 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

So, let's talk about pointer arithmetic for a second.  Given a pointer to any type `T`:

```
T *p;
```

the expression `p+1` will evaluate to the address of the next *object* of type `T`.  So if `T` is `int`, then `p+1` will give us the address of the next *`int` object* after `p`.  If `p` is `0x8000` and `sizeof (int)` is 4, then `p+1` evaluates to `0x8004`.

Where things get fun is if we're working with array expressions.  Assume the following:

```
T a[N];
```

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and its value will be the address of the first element of the array.

So if we write

```
int a[10];
int *p = a + 1;
```

the expression `a` is converted from "10-element array of `int`" to "pointer to `int`", and the value of `a` is the address of the first element (i.e., `&a[0]`).  So the expression `a + 1` gives us the address of the next *integer* object following `a`, which just happens to be `&a[1]`<sup>1</sup>.

Now assume we're working with a 2-D array:

```
int a[2][3];
int (*p)[3] = a + 1;
```

The expression `a` has type "2-element array of 3-element array of `int`".  In this case, `a` "decays" to type "pointer to 3-element array of `int`", or `int (*)[3]`. So `a + 1` gives us the address of the next *3-element array of `int`". Again, assuming `a` starts at `0x8000` and `sizeof (int)` is 4, then `a + 1` evaluates to `0x800c`

---

<sup>1.  The expression `a[i]` is evaluated as `*(a+i)`; that is, we're offsetting `i` elements from the address specified by `a` and dereferencing the result.  Note that this treats `a` as a pointer, not an array.  In the B language (from which C is derived), the array object `a` would have been a pointer object that contained the address of the first element (`a[0]`).  Ritchie changed that in C so that the array expression would be converted to a pointer expression as necessary.</sup>